# python script advanced scheduling

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I'm trying to do something really complicated. Using a Windows box, I'm try to get a script to run every half-an-hour, Mon-Fri, 9:00am-7:00pm, skipping certain dates I define as "holidays". I would love for Python to run this script itself. I've looked into 'apschedule', but can't seem to find the right options I need to do this. If not able to do this through Python, what other solutions can I look at?

By the way, as of right now, I'm running Python 3.3, but am willing to downgrade if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

decorate your job-functions to skip the special days:

```
from datetime import date

def not_on(dates):
    def noop(): pass
    def decor(fn):
        if date.today() in dates:
            return noop
        else:
            return fn
    return decor


@not_on( ( date(2013, 03, 01), ) )
def job():
    print "yeah"
```

then just schedule your jobs for the regular dates and done. if the job is called on a special day the decorator will just skip execution.

just keep using `apscheduler`.

Comment: Can i use the same script to make it run only during business hours?

Comment: sure, just decorate it with a 2nd decorator: `@business_hours` looks nice. you can stack them together.

Comment: The date check here runs on import, not when the job is scheduled. If you're using APScheduler, you're likely to have a long-running process scheduling jobs, and this isn't going to work